# Error showing for url when try to run api test script with Newman

Tags: api-testing, postman

I'm beginner to REST API testing. I wrote some scripts for some scenarios using postman and tried to run with Newman. (In there URL defined as environment variable.) Showing errors for that URL when try to run with Newman.Why this is happened. How to resolve this issue.(Error is not showing when directly put the url to request)(snapshot attached here)
[image: snapshot of error]

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer for that

1. Download both collection and env files
2. Store in a folder
3. Using cmd go to folder location( cd {folder path})
4. Type command as below

newman run {collection name.json} -e {env path} {env name.json}